# нужны ли запятые В морозильном ларе, складского помещения для хранения бакалейной группы товаров, хранится продукция с истёкшим сроком годности

Tags: пунктуация

В морозильном ларе складского помещения для хранения бакалейной группы товаров хранится продукция с истёкшим сроком годности

Comment: Вы бы уточнили ситуацию. Морозильный ларь - это принадлежность (ну или некий элемент) складского помещения? Тут трудно найти иной правдоподобный смысл, но еще труднее поверить, что в этом случае  кто-то захочет запятые ставить. А вот если морозильный ларь - это и есть само "складское помещение" то запятые, конечно, нужны. Но очень трудно в подобную терминологию представить..Да и грамматика фразы тогда нарушена.

Answer (score 1):

Запятые не нужны. С истЕкшим сроком годности.

Answer (score 1):

Все-таки думаю так.
*В морозильном ларе складского помещения для хранения бакалейной группы товаров хранится продукция с ист**е**кшим сроком годности.*
Другие варианты просто фантастичны по смыслу.

Сравните.
Во дворе дома, в ящике письменного стола, в кузове машины для перевозки продуктов...
В (морозильном) ларе (складского) помещения
При такой грамматике просто нет даже намека на какие-то основания для запятых.

Иное дело, если бы смысл был иным.

*В морозильном ларе (складск**ом** помещени**и** для хранения...товаров) хранится продукция...*
Но тут явно концы с концами не сходятся. 
Так что без запятых.

*В морозильном ларе складского помещения для хранения бакалейной группы товаров хранится продукция с ист**е**кшим сроком годности.*

Срок годности - он ***истекший*** (прошедший).
**Истёкший** - это, например, бензин из бака. Жидкость какая-то, но не время/срок.

Comment: Я бы изменил и порядок слов: "товаров бакалейной группы" - поскольку "бакалейная группа товаров" - терминологическая абстракция; хранят относящиеся к ней товары, а не "группу", которую они физически образуют.

Comment: @Alex_ander  оно-то, конечно, так. но тут штука такая, что это обозначение скроее всего забито в документах - от технических, до регистрационных. Есть у них план здания, на под цифрой 100500 забит этот самый "ларь бакалейной группы". Ну как бороться-то с этим?! И зачем? Да и не мое это дело стилистику выправлять в документах Роспотребнадзора.